# How do Pools works with JSON-RPC?

Tags: javascript, json-rpc

I have a bad time understanding [this](https://github.com/zone117x/node-cryptonote-pool) code. I wanna know whether what does it do if some miners connected to it sends something like this:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0", 
    "method": "mining.subscribe", 
    "params": {}, 
    "id": 3
}
```

Does it parse it first? Anyone familiar with the software, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: post the code you don't understand here instead of providing a link to a repo

Comment: I am really sorry, I'll try thanks

Comment: this is just an advice to make your question answerable ;)